# Почему вызывается исключение 'is not defined' в main

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суть вопроса: почему данный код выдает исключение?

```
class Cars:
    list = (element1,
    element2,
    element3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    element1 = 'ferrary'
    element2 = 'honda'
    element3 = 'lanos'
    element4 = 'bmw'
    list = Cars.list
    for elem in list:
        elem = 'ok'
```

*NameError: name 'element1' is not defined*

Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Потому что на момент определения класса `Cars` переменные `element1` - `element3` еще не определены.

Answer (score 0):

**Вы так хотели сделать ?**

```
class Cars:
    def __init__(self, l=[]):
       self.l = list
       self.l = (element1,element2,element3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    element1 = 'ferrary'
    element2 = 'honda'
    element3 = 'lanos'
    element4 = 'bmw'
    list = Cars().l
    for elem in list:
        elem = 'ok'
        print(elem)
```

Comment: Суть в том что-бы использовать атрибут класса нужно добавить ключевое слово "self" к названию атрибута через точку self насколько мне известно переводиться на русский  как "этот" то-есть атрибут этого класса

Comment: А вру ) это "this" в ++ переводится как "это" а self это а аналог this

Comment: В python нет специального `ключевого слова`, аналога `this`. Тк `ссылка` на экземпляр класса передается `через аргументы`. Соответственно `как назовем` первый(нулевой) аргумент, такое и будет `ключевое слово`